SQLAlchemy - MySQL database connection timeouts
I am having a webapp with python as backend. In this webapp, I need a connection to my MySQL database, which I establish by using SQLAlchemy. The problem is that whenever I start my application on the server, the next day I receive this exception, when calling a function that tries to access the database:
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb.OperationalError) (1161, '')
I initialize the connection to the database like this:
db_uri = f'mysql://{db_user}:{db_password}@{db_host}/{db_name}'
engine = create_engine(db_uri, pool_pre_ping=True, pool_recycle=3600)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
Base = declarative_base()

I have read, that others could solve their problem by using pool_pre_ping and pool_recycle but in my case it didn't work. I have also tried to set these parameters in my config like this, but it didn't have any effect either:
SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {"pool_pre_ping": True, "pool_recycle": 3600}

How else can I ensure, that the connection will persist or successfully re-establish?

check the mysql variable settings for - 'wait_timeout' , 'interactive_timeout'  as the mysql backend could be disconnecting you. consult mysql documentation on how to adjust. Also use try/except around operations to handle issues.

Using scoped_session can help with thread safety if that’s an issue. Hopefully, this helps you get past the connection problems! If the issue persists, there might be something specific to your server or network setup that needs looking into.
First off, double-check your MySQL server settings. Sometimes, the server might be closing connections too quickly due to its timeout settings. You might want to look at wait_timeout and interactive_timeout in your MySQL configuration.
Also, make sure you’re closing your sessions properly. It’s easy to accidentally leave them hanging, which can cause issues. Using a context manager to handle your sessions can make things smoother:
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def session_scope():
    session = Session()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()

Adding retry logic around your database operations can also help with those pesky transient issues. And don’t forget to make sure your connection string is spot-on and that you’re using the latest versions of your SQLAlchemy and MySQL packages.
Turning on SQLAlchemy’s logging (echo=True in create_engine) might also give you more clues about what’s going wrong.
Here’s a quick update to your setup that might help:
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

db_uri = f'mysql://{db_user}:{db_password}@{db_host}/{db_name}'
engine = create_engine(
    db_uri,
    pool_pre_ping=True,
    pool_recycle=3600,
    echo=True  # Turn off in production

)
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()

